# How to draw or construct a brachistochrone

Tags: calculus-of-variations, geometric-construction

Since the brachistochrone is such a beautiful curve in our planet, I want to build one somewhere around 1.60 m high. I need a quick way to trace the curve on the material to be cut, e.g. a wide sheet of plywood.

- Which is the most practical way to do this?
- Can this be done as easily as tracing a quarter of a circumference or a quarter of an ellipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brachistochrone is simply an upside-down cycloid. This is [generated by a point on a rolling circle on a flat surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid), so if you can find a fairly flat surface and get a fairly circular object of diameter about 1.60 meters....